# BQ: correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported - where ARRAY_AGG is not practical

Tags: google-bigquery

We have leveraged `ARRAY` and `STRUCT` a lot in BQ, up to a point where we cannot change the content of arrays due to the error in topic.
See below a simple example using public data. Assume `INNER JOIN` will not work because images are missing, on purpose or in error.

Now, I know that normally you can move the `left join` from the array redefinition to the `FROM` clause and use `ARRAY_AGG` but this is not always possible.

In our case, the "other fields" outside of the array-to-update are other arrays or structs - like the `github-nested` table.

Since you cannot do a `SELECT DISTINCT` on `STRUCT` or `ARRAY` fields, you end up being required to UNNEST everything and re-create the table from scratch with many ARRAY_AGG, lot of resource consumption and risk of OOM. This is impossible for tables with a lot of nested fields.

```
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(webDetection),
  STRUCT(
    webDetection.partialMatchingImages,
    webDetection.pagesWithMatchingImages,
    webDetection.fullMatchingImages,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT
        fmi.score,
        fmi.url,
        i.object_id
      FROM
        data.webDetection.fullMatchingImages fmi
      LEFT JOIN
        `bigquery-public-data.the_met.images` i
      ON
        fmi.url = i.original_image_url
      ) AS fullMatchingImages_from_met,
    webDetection.webEntities
  ) AS webDetection
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.the_met.vision_api_data` data
```

Any idea how to avoid re-aggregating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that conceptually your query correct and the only issue is with the error `correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported` - try replacing below fragment

```
FROM
  data.webDetection.fullMatchingImages fmi
LEFT JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.the_met.images` i
ON
  fmi.url = i.original_image_url
```

with

```
FROM
  data.webDetection.fullMatchingImages fmi
CROSS JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.the_met.images` i
WHERE
  fmi.url = i.original_image_url
```

> Update, to add not matching urls

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(webDetection),
  STRUCT(
    webDetection.partialMatchingImages,
    webDetection.pagesWithMatchingImages,
    webDetection.fullMatchingImages,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT *      
      FROM t.webDetection.fullMatchingImages_from_met_temp
      UNION ALL
      SELECT AS STRUCT *, NULL
      FROM t.webDetection.fullMatchingImages
      WHERE NOT url IN (SELECT url FROM t.webDetection.fullMatchingImages_from_met_temp)
    ) AS fullMatchingImages_from_met,
    webDetection.webEntities
    ) AS webDetection
FROM (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(webDetection),
    STRUCT(
      webDetection.partialMatchingImages,
      webDetection.pagesWithMatchingImages,
      webDetection.fullMatchingImages,
      ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT
          fmi.score,
          fmi.url,
          i.object_id
        FROM data.webDetection.fullMatchingImages fmi
        JOIN `bigquery-public-data.the_met.images` i
        ON fmi.url = i.original_image_url
      ) AS fullMatchingImages_from_met_temp,
      webDetection.webEntities
    ) AS webDetection
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.the_met.vision_api_data` data
) t
```

Comment: Would that not result in the same as an inner join ? I would miss the left-side `url`s that have no matching image. To illustrate, assume I have a `COALESCE(i.original_image_url, "No image")` in the SELECT

Comment: in your result - you have two repeated records `webDetection.fullMatchingImages` and `webDetection.fullMatchingImages_from_met` . the first one has all initial and the second one has those which has matching object. do you really need redundant stuff in second one?  But yes - you are right - in my original answer I have focused on error you were getting :o)

Comment: see update in the answer  - I think it is what you were looking for (at least result-wise)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail ! I like splitting the `LEFT JOIN` into matching in the `FROM` clause and then reference that in the `ARRAY` with `NOT IN`. In my case, turns to be `NOT STRUCT() IN` because of composite keys but that worked ! One caveat (see other answer) but will accept ;o)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on above answer, it could be that a query - another one for me - fails because the optimizer still think the subquery is too complicated.

In that case, try avoiding `UNION ALL` and use `ARRAY_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(webDetection),

  STRUCT(
    webDetection.partialMatchingImages,
    webDetection.pagesWithMatchingImages,
    webDetection.fullMatchingImages,

    ARRAY_CONCAT(
     ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT *      
      FROM t.webDetection.fullMatchingImages_from_met_temp
     ),
     ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT *, NULL
      FROM t.webDetection.fullMatchingImages
      WHERE NOT url IN (SELECT url FROM t.webDetection.fullMatchingImages_from_met_temp)
     ) 
    ) AS fullMatchingImages_from_met, 

    webDetection.webEntities
    ) AS webDetection
FROM (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(webDetection),
    STRUCT(
      webDetection.partialMatchingImages,
      webDetection.pagesWithMatchingImages,
      webDetection.fullMatchingImages,
      ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT
          fmi.score,
          fmi.url,
          i.object_id
        FROM data.webDetection.fullMatchingImages fmi
        JOIN `bigquery-public-data.the_met.images` i
        ON fmi.url = i.original_image_url
      ) AS fullMatchingImages_from_met_temp,
      webDetection.webEntities
    ) AS webDetection
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.the_met.vision_api_data` data
) t
```

BQ accepted that and interestingly, it turned out to be even faster than `UNION ALL` ! Almost same runtime as an `ARRAY(... INNER JOIN...)`

On the other hand, even with those verbose workarounds - which may not last - `BigQuery` optimizer needs further tuning. Referring to the original error message `Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN`, a simple `LEFT JOIN` is quite efficient to me...

@readers, FYI there is bug filed for that [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71699514). Make sure to "star" it to up its priority !

Comment: Full disclaimer and credit: I got the hint on enriching, filtering rows & columns existing ARRAYs from this article: https://hackernoon.com/bigquery-level-up-your-queries-with-these-advanced-tricks-c87de1fde235